# DisplayMemberPath property of combo box not working as expected with source being a dictionary with custom key

Tags: wpf, combobox

I am having a `ComboBox` in [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) which is having its source as a `IDictionary<Key, String>` where 'Key' is the custom key. The `ComboBox` is defined as follows:

```
<ComboBox 
    x:Name="MD_PDIR_COMBO_SOURCE"
    Grid.Row="0" 
    Style="{DynamicResource USButtonComboBoxStyle}"
    Margin="14,5"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SourcesComboList}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Value"
    SelectedValuePath="Key"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedSource}"
    SelectionChanged="MD_PDIR_COMBO_SOURCE_SelectionChanged" 
/>
```

Now the issue I am facing is, although `DisplayMemberPath` is set to the "Value" of the dictionary which is a `String`, the Visual text being displayed in the combo box on selecting an item is BLANK/EMPTY.

Although all the desired functions on combo box selection change are happening correctly but the values/text is not shown after we select an item.

Kindly help!

Comment: `Combobox` displays text correctly with IDictionary<object,string> as ItemsSource. The problem may be in `Style` or in the collection you use as source. Hard to tell as you didn\`t show any of that.

Answer (score 7):

Does your style set the `ItemTemplate` at all?

Setting `DisplayMemberPath` is a shortcut way of saying the `ItemTemplate` should be a `TextBlock` with it's `Text` bound to whatever is in `DisplayMemberPath`, so setting the `ItemTemplate` in addition to `DispalyMemberPath` will override it and make `DisplayMemberPath` useless

Comment: This scenario can occur when a `Theme` applied to the whole project imposes an `ItemTemplate`: suddenly the UI is broken because of a style change elsewhere. Overriding with a local `ItemTemplate` solved it.

Answer (score 7):

This work OK

```
public string Value{ get; set; }
```

This doesen't work !

```
public string Value;
```

Conclusion: DisplayMemberPath indicates a property of your item object not a field. Use getter and setter: { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

i assume that you have a dictionary like this?

```
SourcesComboList = Dictionary<string,string>();
```

if you just wanna check wether your Displaymemberpath works alter your combobox to this

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SourcesComboList}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Value" 
          SelectedValuePath="Key">
 </ComboBox>
```

if this is working the problem is not DisplayMemberPath :)

Comment: SourcesComboList is property which returns IDictionary<Key, String> where Key is class used for defining custom key

Comment: when you change the combobox to my posted code - do you see a list of your values?

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem with internal property.

The DisplayMemberPath is working only for public properties.

I guess the issue with the original question might be ComboBox does not query the Dictionary to know its Item Type instead it looks at the individual Dictionary Item (not the Value) which does not have any Key and Value properties.